# How do I apply a GraphQL schema to Dgraph?

Tags: graphql, dgraph

I'm working on a project for which a graph database makes the most sense as storage. My schema is something that I need to be fairly malleable, so I don't want to have to write resolvers up front, so Dgraph, which speaks GraphQL natively, makes a lot of sense during this period of quick iteration.

I've been over the Dgraph docs but I'm having difficulty finding out how to insert a schema into the database. I have tried simply sending a POST request via curl to the /admin endpoint containing my schema, but I get 400s reporting bad requests.

Given a GraphQL schema on disk, how can I upload the schema into Dgraph?